# GSTARcad transient graphics

Tags: c#, autocad, cad

I am trying to create transient graphics like in autocad, but it drops me memory coruption error. I will attach some code that works in autocad but not in GSTARcad. I think that EraseTransients is not working correct.

Does anybody know how to fix it?
I know about UpdateTransient function, but it is not what i need for my purposes.

```
using Gssoft.Gscad.DatabaseServices;
using Gssoft.Gscad.EditorInput;
using Gssoft.Gscad.Geometry;
using Gssoft.Gscad.GraphicsInterface;
using Gssoft.Gscad.Runtime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using acGI = Gssoft.Gscad.GraphicsInterface;

namespace GStarTransient
{ 
    public class Class1
    {
        Editor ed = Gssoft.Gscad.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        DBObjectCollection markers = null;
        TransientManager tm = acGI.TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager;

        [CommandMethod("trc")]
        public void TransientStart()
        {
            PointMonitorEventHandler handler = null;

            handler = delegate (object sender, PointMonitorEventArgs e)
            {
                Point3d point = e.Context.RawPoint;
                UpdateTransient(point);
            };

            ed.PointMonitor += handler;
        }

        private void UpdateTransient(Point3d point)
        {
            RemoveTransient();
            markers = new DBObjectCollection();

            Line line1 = new Line(Point3d.Origin, point);
            AddTransient(line1);
            Line line2 = new Line(Point3d.Origin, new Point3d(point.X - 50, point.Y, point.Z));
            AddTransient(line2);
        }

        private void AddTransient(Entity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                entity.LineWeight = LineWeight.LineWeight030;
                entity.ColorIndex = 1;
                tm.AddTransient(entity, acGI.TransientDrawingMode.DirectShortTerm, 128, new IntegerCollection());
                markers.Add(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void RemoveTransient() 
        {
            try
            {
                if (markers != null)
                {
                    tm.EraseTransients(acGI.TransientDrawingMode.DirectShortTerm, 128, new IntegerCollection());

                    foreach (DBObject dBObject in markers)
                        dBObject.Dispose();

                    markers = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GSTAR is LIKE AUTOCAD but not fully compatible.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GstarCAD

Comment: @jdweng GstarCAD's GRX API means that software written for AutoCADs ARX API can run on both without changes to the code. Quote from your source. They have transient manager as in autocad, but i think it just do not work properly.

Comment: It says "as well as an interface which is very similar to that of AutoCAD".  Similar does not mean ALWAYS.  What versions are you using?  Check Task Manager and verify memory usage when error occurs.  I would also check that dBObject is not null before disposing.

Comment: @jdweng I have everything that you told me in my project at work, but it doesn't work as well

Comment: GSTARcad may use more memory and run slower than AUTOCAD.  Switching apps often the performance is not the same as original app.